# Render pdf links with qtwebengine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtwebengine

I would like to know how to make qtwebengine based browser to open any pdf links, such as http://openedgroup.org/books/Chemistry.pdf this one.

I already have this enabled:

```
self.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True);
```

but it cannot open link (does not jump pages either).
I'm using Qt 5.9.

Comment: There is no built-in support for rendering pdf or postscript in Qt. It can write it, but it cannot read it. See: [Handling PDF](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF).

Comment: See also [QTBUG-50556](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50556), and [Create QPdfJs](https://yshurik.github.io/post/create-qpdfjs/) for a possible work-around.